# I can't build expo app (:app:mergeReleaseResources)

Tags: react-native, expo

I build expo app yesterday. 
But I can't build expo app today (another app).
I don't update at all. 
I search google but can't get any answer
exp build:android

this is expo app build log

```
FAILED
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > java.util.concur rent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource 
compilation failed
[stderr]   /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk33/android-shell-
app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG 
signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
 or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

`

Comment: Your file `/app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk33/android-shell-
app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG 
signature: file does not start with PNG signature.` seems to be corrupted. Can you open it with an image editor ? Try to replace it with a new version.
Also try to build -> rebuild

Comment: I can't find the direction of file

Comment: @Euro check yourproject/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi

Comment: there's no android folder in my project folder, but I search minmap-xxhdpi folder(projectfolder/node_modules/react-native/template/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi), so I replace it, but it doesn't work

Comment: I solve this problem by changing assets to default, but I don't understand why it fails to read my icon & splash

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue too, and I resolved it by using "expo-cli build:android -t apk" instead of "exp build:android". This built the apk without any errors and all the images rendered perfectly.
Make sure you have expo-cli installed.